# Which codec + encryption method makes it easy for streaming J2ME video playback?

Tags: video, java-me, streaming, encryption

I want to transport video files from a desktop system to my mobile device, but I want the videos to be encrypted so the mobile video files cannot be viewed elsewhere.  This means I can't decrypt the whole file, I need to decrypt it as a stream.

Question:  What's the best codec and encryption method to use to make the decryption easier?

Naively encrypting the video and randomly choosing a codec doesn't work, since the J2ME media players (like the one on the Blackberry) tend to require "random seek" which hops around the file (thus requiring an entire file decryption).

Thoughts on:

1. Codecs that don't require random seek access to the entire video?
2. An example of viewing a video in the J2ME environment that can grab a block of the video, decrypt it and play it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out [3GP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3GP) is a codec which doesn't require a forward seek-a-head.